# Can you make a Deeplink in a browser to open "share to story" in instagram?

Tags: ios, android-intent, browser, instagram, deeplink

I would like to have a "share to instagram stories" functionality in a webapplication. I was hoping i could do that with iOS urls and Android intents (in url form).

Is it possible to deeplink from a browser on android to share an image into the story mode?

I was starting from this linke, to open instagram on android phones:
instagram story test

But I cannot find any good resources that explain how to do this with stories. On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/ it is described how it works for proper Apps with intents, but i was hoping it was possible to creat a link out of that too.

Anyone has done something like that or can tell me the scheme of such an URL?

href="intent://WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;action=WHAT_ACTION";scheme=https;end">
how and where to add an image... and where would be com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY?

Or if that is not possible at all, and the most I can get from a browser is opening instagram?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, [these](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) are the only supported hooks documented for instagram.